# seaborn violinplot and boxplot side by side

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot, violin-plot

I want to compare side by side seaborn vilonplot with boxplot.
This my dataset sample:

```
   group     points
0      A  12.432848
1      A  13.246483
2      A  13.812403
3      A  13.212260
4      A  15.307191
5      B  13.464179
6      B  11.695743
7      B  12.197824
8      B  13.892186
9      B   9.586561
10     C  18.071026
11     C  18.522597
12     C  17.649151
13     C  18.266435
14     C  17.088155
```

I know I can get boxplot with `sns.boxplot(data=df, x="group", y="points", hue="group")` and violinplot with `sns.violinplot(data=df, x="group", y="points", hue="group")` but I'd like them attached, half boxplot and half violinplot, as in the below picture.
[image: Id like to get this but half violinplot half boxplot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there really an interest in doing this? The violinplot already incorporates a small boxplot in its center.

Nevertheless, this is achievable by using a fake hue level and switching the order between the two graphs:

```
df2 = df.assign(hue=1)
sns.boxplot(data=df2, x="group", y="points", hue="hue", hue_order=[1,0])
g = sns.violinplot(data=df2, x="group", y="points", hue="hue", split=True, hue_order=[0,1])
g.legend_.remove() # hide legend
```

[image: boxplot + violinplot]

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

You don't have three dimensions like the image you showed. I believe you simply want:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

example_data = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        [
         ['A', 12],
         ["A", 15],
         ["A", 18],
         ["B", 11],
         ["B", 10],
         ["B", 8]
        ]
    )
)

example_data.columns = ['group', 'points']

sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.violinplot(
    data=example_data,
    x='group',
    y='points'
)
```

**Output:**

[image: violin plot]

I'd reference https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html for further customization and documentation